# Error- undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the error `undefined method`each' for nil:NilClass`

I have read the posts about it, but I still can't figure out what's wrong.

Here is my controller:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @blog = Blog.new
  end

  def create
    @blog = Blog.new(blog_params)

    if @blog.save
      redirect_to @blog
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def index

  end

  private

    def blog_params
      params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :body, :image)
    end

end
```

And my view for index.html.erb:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
    <h3><%= @post.title %></h3>
    <div><%= @post.body %></div>
    <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```

The full error was `undefined method`each' for nil:NilClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `index` method returns nothing. It should be like this:

```
  def index
    @blogs = Blog.all
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

@post is not defined.  You should be outputting the `blog` object:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
    <h3><%= blog.title %></h3>
    <div><%= blog.body %></div>
    <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```